# Sum of random number of independent random variables (with dependency)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, characteristic-functions

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n, \ldots,$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables each with probability mass function
\begin{equation}
p_X(k) = 
\begin{cases}
1/6, \quad k = -1,\\
2/3, \quad k = 0,\\
1/6, \quad k = 1,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and let $N$ be the smallest $n$ such that $X_n = 0$. I wish to determine the characteristic function of $S_N = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$.

Attempt:

The characteristic function of $S_N$ is

$\varphi_{S_N}(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{itS_N}] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[e^{itS_N}|N]] 
= \mathbb{E}[h(N)] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty h(n) p_N(n)$,

and $p_N(n) = \frac{2}{3} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n-1}$ since $\{N = n\} \Leftrightarrow \{X_0 \neq 0, \ldots, X_{n-1} \neq 0, X_n = 0\}$. Furthermore,

$h(n) = \mathbb{E}[e^{itS_N}|N=n] = \mathbb{E}[e^{itS_n}|N=n] = \sum_{x_1 \neq 0}\cdots\sum_{x_{n-1} \neq 0} e^{it \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} X_j} p_{X_1, \ldots, X_n | N=n}(x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}, 0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define $X_1$ s.t.
$$P(X_1=k)=\begin{cases}
p&k=1\\
1-2p&k=0\\
p&k=-1
\end{cases},\,p\in [0,1/2)$$
We define $N=\inf\{n:X_n=0\}$; so $P(N>k)=(2p)^k$ which implies $P(N=k)=(2p)^{k-1}(1-2p)$. Now if $N=n$ the $X_1,...,X_n$ are conditionally independent; also for $k<n$
$$P(X_k=1|N=n)=P(X_k=-1|N=n)=1/2
$$
and for $k=n$, $P(X_k=0|N=n)=1$. So
$$E[e^{i\xi(X_1+...+X_N)}]=\sum_{n\geq 1}\cos(\xi)^{n-1}(2p)^{n-1}(1-2p)=\frac{1-2p}{1-2p\cos(\xi)}$$